# How to confirm the port is available before connecting with reverse SSH

Tags: networking, ssh, cloud

To set a reverse SSH connection I specify the `ssh -R` command line flag followed by a remote machine's port `2210` to map it to a `localhost:22` of the machine requesting a reverse ssh connection:

```
ssh -R 2210:localhost:22  user-001@ec1-23-456-789-0.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Is there a way to check if the remote port `2210` is already in use and raise an error if if the port is not available?

Comment: Use the `telnet` client to open the port at that IP address.  We use it all of the time when authoring TCP network code.  [DuckDuckGoSearch](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=telnet+test+port+open+&t=newext&atb=v276-1&ia=web).  If you are talking programmatically for each connection, please clarify that in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `ExitOnForwardFailure`
> Specifies whether `ssh(1)` should terminate the connection if it cannot set up all requested dynamic, tunnel, local, and remote port forwardings, (e.g. if either end is unable to bind and listen on a specified port). […] The argument must be `yes` or `no` (the default).

<sup>(source: [`man 5 ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ExitOnForwardFailure))</sup>

Specify it as a command-line option:

```
ssh -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -R …
```

or in `~/.ssh/config`, or in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Comment: Oh MAN!  I hate an answer that is better than my comment :)  +1